# locally host firebase backend with react frontend together, for debugging

Tags: reactjs, firebase, debugging, testing

I am building a react website with firebase functions backend.

I'm using `firebase serve` to locally host the node.js backend that I connect to my react code through express API endpoints, and I am using `react-scripts start` to test my react frontend app.

all my get requests in my react app use `/some endpoint` to communicate with my firebase localserver. But they are running on different ports. firebase serves it on `localhost:5000` while react live server hosts it at `localhost:3000`.

I tried many things and couldn't get any useful way to make this work. I at last added my react project as a subfolder in my firebase project and made the hosting public path at `firebase.json` to my react `build` directory. It works now but I always have to run `npm run build` on my react app on every change, to make it compile my app into the `build` directory, which is painfully slow.

What is the proper way to do this? debug react app and firebase backend together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally enabled `cross-origin-requests` on my server using `cors` module

### Serverside code

```
const cors = require("cors");


app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    return cors()(req, res, async () => {
        res.send("working...");
    });
});
```

### Serverside code

And then adding a simple config file in the react side, to switch between debugging and deployed testing really helped.

config.js

```
var domain = "";
// domain = "http://localhost:5000";

export {domain}
```

then whenever I use apis in react, I simply comment/uncomment the second line to switch between local and deployed testing.

---

Then whenever I use APIs, I append `domain` before every url in all references, eg fetch requests

```
import { domain } from "config.js";

fetch(domain + "/int-search", ...
```

Then it worked fine running both the firebase backend and the react application on localhost, using `firebase serve` and `npm start` for my react app.